# Birational morphism and etale base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question which is probably well known. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a birational morphism of reduced schemes and $Y_1\rightarrow Y$ be an étale morphism. Is it true that $X\times_Y Y_1\rightarrow Y_1$ is birational?

Comment: What definition of birational are you using and do you have any other restrictions on your schemes or just reduced over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Dear @Dori: "reduced" is an absolute concept for a scheme $X$ , not depending on $X$ being over $\mathbb Z$ or over any other scheme.

Comment: Oh I worded that wrong! I meant is he assuming anything else other than reduced for example is he just working over $\mathbb{Z}$ or over a field. The reason I asked is because I haven't seen people talk about birational morphisms other than for schemes over fields so I wasn't sure if the concept was still similar over more general bases.

Comment: @hjia: this is true for any open morphism $Y_1\to Y$, and étale morphisms are open.